# How to check if an api call has completed

Tags: javascript

I have a script in my code

```
<script src="https://geodata.solutions/includes/statecity.js"></script>
```

which is making an ajax call. This script is used to fetch states and cities and loads the value in select. How do I check whether that particular call is complete as it is in this external script and I want to set value of select using javascript/jquery

I am currently using setTimeout for setting select value and delaying it randomly for 6 seconds however it's not the right approach. Also, I have tried putting the code to set value in $(document).ready() but the api call returns the values later

```
        setTimeout(function(){ 
        jQuery("#stateId").val('<?php echo $rowaddress['state']; ?>').change();
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            jQuery("#cityId").val('<?php echo $rowaddress['city']; ?>').change();
        }, 3000);
    }, 6000);
```

Comment: Is `statecity.js` your code?  It handles the ajax calls internally so there seems little opportunity to know when they have completed

Comment: i think you want to use promises

Comment: I would look into statecity.js and somehow use the success callback, but that depends.

Comment: no @Martin its not my code...

Comment: @Kevin.a I thought have promises as well but couldn't figure how to approach it

Comment: Even if you used jQuery’s `ajaxSetup` method before embedding this script, that would only apply default values to AJAX calls that don’t get explicitly overwritten by the actual call. I don’t think there is any reasonable way to achieve what you want. _“its not my code”_ - but does it change frequently, or is anything about it “dynamic”? If not, you could probably easily _make_ it your code, by storing a copy of the script on your own server, and making the changes you need in there.

Comment: I guess the calls are dynamic so probably I can make changes in the js file however I was looking for a more direct approach ... as you can see the values that I intend to set are being fetched through a SQL query and echoed using PHP tags @04FS

Comment: that was a syntax error while posting the question. I have made the edit @chrispbacon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spy on `jQuery.ajax`:

```
jQuery.ajax = new Proxy(jQuery.ajax, {
  apply: function(target, thisArg, argumentsList) {
    const req = target.apply(thisArg, argumentsList);
    const rootUrl = '//geodata.solutions/api/api.php';
    if (argumentsList[0].url.indexOf(rootUrl) !== -1) {
      req.done(() => console.log(`request to ${argumentsList[0].url} completed`))
    }
    return req;
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the solution.. a little addition w.r.t my requirement and it worked perfect...

Answer (score 1):

Having a look through the code for `statecity.js`, I've just seen that:

```
jQuery(".states").prop("disabled",false);
```

is executed upon completion of initial loading.  This is on line 150 of the source code.

You *could* monitor the `disabled` attribute of the `.states` selector to be informed when the activity is completed using the handy JQuery extension `watch`.

To detect the completion of the event, just watch the disabled property of the `.states` item:

```
$('.states').watch('disabled', function() {
    console.log('disabled state changed');
    // Add your post-loading code here (or call the function that contains it)
});
```

**Note that this is extremely hacky**.  If the author of `statecity.js` changes their code, this could stop working immediately or could behave unexpectedly.

It is always very risky to rely on tinkering in someone else's code when you have no control over changes to it.  **Use this solution with caution**.

Unfortunately, the original link to the `watch` extension code seems to have expired, but here it is (*not my code but reproduced from author*):

```
// Function to watch for attribute changes
// http://darcyclarke.me/development/detect-attribute-changes-with-jquery
$.fn.watch = function(props, callback, timeout){
    if(!timeout)
        timeout = 10;
    return this.each(function(){
        var el         = $(this),
            func     = function(){ __check.call(this, el) },
            data     = {    props:     props.split(","),
                        func:     callback,
                        vals:     [] };
        $.each(data.props, function(i) { data.vals[i] = el.attr(data.props[i]); });
        el.data(data);
        if (typeof (this.onpropertychange) == "object"){
            el.bind("propertychange", callback);
        } else {
            setInterval(func, timeout);
        }
    });
    function __check(el) {
        var data     = el.data(),
            changed = false,
            temp    = "";
        for(var i=0;i < data.props.length; i++) {
            temp = el.attr(data.props[i]);
            if(data.vals[i] != temp){
                data.vals[i] = temp;
                changed = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(changed && data.func) {
            data.func.call(el, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hey tried the code but didn't work. It gives an error at $.browser.mozilla.
Cannot read property 'mozilla' of undefined

Comment: Sorry the code for `watch` is legacy and is based on jQuery before 1.9 (when `$.browser` was removed).  I'll edit the code and you can give it another try